# imaplib SSL connections hang in CLOSE_WAIT after closing

Tags: python, ssl, tcp, imap, imaplib

I have a python code that connects to IMAP server via IMAP4_SSL, and everything works fine until it tries to close the connection with this:

```
def logout(self):
    "Close the mailbox and logout and set the connection to None"
    try:
        self.connection.close()
        self.connection.logout()
    except e:
        pass
    self.connection = None
```

This leaves the connection in CLOSE_WAIT state:

```
 tcp       38      0 1.2.3.4:55809        5.6.7.8:993 CLOSE_WAIT  18983/python2.6
```

Where it remains for a prolonged time. The python process itself is a long-running daemon that does IMAP checks periodically, so these accumulate with time. Any ideas why it might be happening and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It might be useful to see the rest of the code.

Comment: I'm having the same issue actually - were you able to resolve this or at least find a workaround?

Comment: @NFicano unfortunately, not yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sockets hang out in CLOSE_WAIT when they haven't been closed by the local program.

Looking at the imaplib [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/imaplib.py), the only place that `self.sock.close()` is called is in `shutdown()`.

My guess is you need to call `self.connection.shutdown()`.

*update:* As Bruno notes, `logout()` calls `shutdown()`. However, the way the example code is structured, if `close()` raises an exeception then `logout()`will be silently skipped... and `shutdown()` won't be called. I wonder if that's what's going on.

Comment: Hmm... I was sure close() actually, well, closes everything, but looks like I was mistaken. Also I thought the destructor should do it, but that doesn't seem to happen either. Thanks, I'll try with shutdown.

Comment: It looks like `logout` calls `shutdown`.

Comment: Not sure why this is an answered question... the answer was "call shutdown", but logout *does* call shutdown.   So, why is it hanging?